# Check if checkbox is checked then send

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have this markup:

```
<form action="http://acumbamail.com/signup/13565/" method="POST">
    <input type="checkbox" id="privacidad-btn" > Acepto política de privacidad<br>
    <input type="button" value="Enviar" id="submit_acumba">
</form>
```

I want that if the user clicks on the `button` without checkbox checked there is an alert that he must agree to the terms (check the `checkbox`). Any ideas on the best approach to this?

I'm starting doing this way but don't know how which way to go:

```
if (jQuery("#privacidad-btn").is(":checked")) {

}
```

Comment: You have used correct condition. what is not working??

Comment: I'm don't know how to go it from there. I mean, if I put an alert() inside the condition, the button anyway sends the info even if the checkbox is not checked.

Comment: :you need to write the condition in button click event. have look at tymeJVs answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach that i like with html5 is the form validation

just put `required` on the checkbox and when the try to submit it they will be alerted with a popover dialog in there own language (its a good highlighter in the form of what is wrong with it)

```
<input required type="checkbox" id="privacidad-btn">
```

You could do it the way tymeJV suggest with button clicked event `$("#submit_acumba").click(...)`
That way you would support more browsers. but: It would just only validate on a click of a button

But there is the form submit event as well.

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
    if ( ! jQuery("#privacidad-btn").is(":checked")) {
        // Not checked abort the default submit
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

The difference is that it has to do all the native form validation before -> if it is invalid it won't trigger a submit or call the function
with button.onclick it would avoid the native validation since it would run before the submit event

Answer (score 0):

You need a handler for the button as well:

```
$("#submit_acumba").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (jQuery("#privacidad-btn").is(":checked")) {
        //submit!
    }  
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this straight and simple HTML implementation, you can do this without any special scripting (JavaScript/jQuery):

```
<form>
<p><input type="checkbox" required name="terms"> I accept the <u>Terms and Conditions</u></p>
<p><input type="submit"></p>
</form>
```

Here's a JSFiddle link where you can play with this implementation: http://jsfiddle.net/zs9b167b/